# Is there a way to get all logging providers, and for each their LogLevel settings?

Tags: asp.net-core, ilogger, iloggerfactory

For the ASP.NET ILogger system, is there a way to get all providers that are running in my app? And then for each provider get the LogLevels set for that provider?

I want to log the logging as it's configured.

I'm running Blazor server side on .NET 8 if that makes a difference.

I initialize my loggers as follows:

```
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Adding dev logging providers");
    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddJsonConsole();
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
    builder.Logging.AddFileLogger();
    builder.Logging.AddAzureBlobLogger();
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Adding production logging providers");
    builder.Logging.AddAzureBlobLogger();
    builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
    builder.Services.Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
        options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
        options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
    });
}

// connect to ApplicationInsights
if (config.GetValue<bool>("ApplicationInsights:Enabled"))
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Connect to Application Insights");
    builder.Logging.AddApplicationInsights();
    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
}
```

Note: `AddFileLogger()` and `AddAzureBlobLogger()` are loggers I created (after spending 2 days trying and failing to get SeriLog to work logging to Azure BLOB storage).

What is driving me on this is I want to make sure my `AzureBlobLogger` has connected to Azure BLOB storage successfully. Secondarily, I'd like to log the log levels to verify I have those set correctly (I had a case where there was an override I was not aware of).

Comment: While directly retrieving all ILoggerProvider instances and their corresponding LogLevel settings isn't supported in ASP.NET Core, there are alternative approaches to achieve your goal of logging the logging configuration. Could you share your current configuration or if you have tried anything.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I added how I initialize all this to the question. TIA